# jQuery duplicating div on resize events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is a piece of code inside of a magento view.phtml file that was put there to control an out of stock functionality. It only displays on the page when the product is not saleable.

It works as intended, to a point. However on mobile devices such as an iPad or when the user resizes the viewport (even when inspecting for example) it causes a duplication of the div in question and eventually causes the browser to 'crash' the page.

The code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                
                jQuery('.sharing-links').appendTo(jQuery('.current_configuration_bottom'));
                jQuery('.configured-bundles-wrap').appendTo(jQuery('.current_configuration_bottom'));

                function isElementOutViewport(el) {
                    el = document.getElementById(el);
                    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                    return rect.bottom < 0 || rect.right < 0 || rect.left > window.innerWidth || rect.top > window.innerHeight;
                }

                function setBuyBox() {
                    var width = jQuery(window).width();
                    var right_description = jQuery('.right_description');
                    var is_iPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

                    if (( width >= 998 || is_iPad )) {

                        right_description.appendTo('.product-sidebar');
                        right_description.addClass('stick-right');
                        right_description.css('top', '250px');
                        var rightContent = jQuery('.current_configuration');

                        var stick_right = jQuery('#header .container').offset().left
                        var stick_width = (22 / width) * jQuery('#header .container').outerWidth();
                        var rightCol_offset_top = right_description.offset().top - 205;

                        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
                            var stop_offset_top = jQuery('#bottom').offset().top - right_description.outerHeight() - 250;
                            if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > rightCol_offset_top && jQuery(window).scrollTop() < stop_offset_top) {
                                if (is_iPad) {
                                    // console.log('case 1');
                                    rightContent.css('top', '200px');
                                    rightContent.css({
                                        'position': 'fixed',
                                        'width': '223px',
                                        'max-width': '100%',
                                        'right': 'auto',
                                        'bottom': 'auto'
                                    });
                                    rightContent.removeClass("stick-right-bottom");
                                    rightContent.removeClass("stick-right");


                                    var footerOutView = isElementOutViewport('footer-container');
                                    var headerOutView = isElementOutViewport('header');
                                    if (!headerOutView) {
                                        rightContent.css({
                                            'position': 'static',
                                            'top': '0',
                                            'bottom': 'auto',
                                            'right': 'auto'
                                        });
                                    }

                                    if (!footerOutView) {
                                        rightContent.css({
                                            'position': 'absolute',
                                            'bottom': '0',
                                            'top': 'auto',
                                            'right': '0'
                                        });
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    // console.log('case 2');
                                    right_description.css('top', '200px');
                                    right_description.addClass("stick-right");
                                    right_description.removeClass("stick-right-bottom");

                                    rightContent.css('top', '200px');
                                    rightContent.addClass("stick-right");
                                    rightContent.removeClass("stick-right-bottom");

                                    var footerOutView = isElementOutViewport('footer-container');
                                    //console.log(footerInView);
                                    if (!footerOutView) {
                                        rightContent.css('top', 'auto');
                                        rightContent.removeClass('stick-right');
                                        rightContent.addClass('stick-right-bottom');
                                    }

                                    if (is_iPad) {
                                        rightContent.css('top', 'auto');
                                        rightContent.css({
                                            'position': 'absolute',
                                            'bottom': '0',
                                            'top': 'auto',
                                            'right': '0'
                                        });
                                    }
                                }

                            } else if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > stop_offset_top) {
                                // console.log('case 3');
                                right_description.css('top', 'auto');
                                right_description.removeClass("stick-right");
                                right_description.addClass("stick-right-bottom");

                                if (is_iPad) {
                                    // console.log('ipad 3');
                                    rightContent.css({
                                        'position': 'absolute',
                                        'bottom': '0',
                                        'top': 'auto',
                                        'right': '0'
                                    });
                                }

                                var footerOutView = isElementOutViewport('footer-container');
                                //console.log(footerInView);
                                if (!footerOutView) {
                                    rightContent.css('top', 'auto');
                                    rightContent.removeClass('stick-right');
                                    rightContent.addClass('stick-right-bottom');
                                }

                                //rightContent.css({'width':'auto', 'position': 'static'});
                            } else {
                                // console.log('case 4');
                                right_description.css('top', 'auto');
                                right_description.removeClass("stick-right");
                                right_description.removeClass("stick-right-bottom");
                                rightContent.css('top', '200px');

                                var footerOutView = isElementOutViewport('footer-container');
                                //console.log(footerInView);
                                if (!footerOutView) {
                                    rightContent.css('top', 'auto');
                                    rightContent.removeClass('stick-right');
                                    rightContent.addClass('stick-right-bottom');
                                }

                                if (is_iPad) {
                                    var headerOutView = isElementOutViewport('header');
                                    //console.log(headerOutView);
                                    if (!footerOutView || !headerOutView) {
                                        rightContent.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'width': 'auto'});
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // console.log('case 5');
                        //right_description.appendTo('.product_details');
                        //right_description.css('top', 'auto');
                        //right_description.removeClass('stick-right');
                    }
                }
            
                jQuery(window).resize(function () {
                    setBuyBox();
                });

                window.onorientationchange = function () {
                    setBuyBox();
                };

                setBuyBox();
            });

        </script>
```

I have tried a couple of things to get this to stop happening, changing `right_description.appendTo('product-sidebar');` to .after however it is still happening.

Im not entirely sure this whole code is necessary to achieve what was originally needed.

Im brushing up on my js/jquery implementation and any pointers on how to clean this code up and fix the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: *any pointers* - you add a *new* scroll event every time you call `setBuyBox` - so after you resize/rotate a few times, your scroll event is called multiple times.  Move it outside the setBuyBox function so `jQuery(window).scroll(function () {` is only called once

Comment: `jQuery('.sharing-links').appendTo(jQuery('.current_configuration_bottom'));` you don't need to appendTo a jquery object, a selector will suffice (should cause a problem as-is though): `jQuery('.sharing-links').appendTo('.current_configuration_bottom');`.   No solution to your actual problem though, sorry.

Comment: thanks for the tips; that makes sense.